# Is this "It could've been more thrilling as I was expecting something more at that time." correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, sequence-of-tenses

I have a confusion with a sentence. Is this sentence correct in grammar-article sense?

> "It could've been more thrilling as I was expecting something more at that time."

I have confusion with "as" and "was expecting" and I wonder if there is a mismatch of tenses in the second part.

I wanted to say, "It could have been more money as he is an honest guy". My confusion is if I use past tense on main clause "It could have been..." and use "as", can I use any tense with the subordinate clause starting with "as"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contemporary American English, we are far more likely to say **since** not **as** in sentences like the following, but **as** and **since** are interchangeable:

> I wonder who took my last beer from the fridge?
>   -- It could have been your roommate, since he drinks first and asks questions later.

As you can see, there is no problem following **could have been** with a present-tense construction in the *since*-clause or *as*-clause.

> It could have been your roommate, as he drinks first and asks
>   questions later.

The subordinate clause there states a persistent fact which is true now and was true then.

Comment: Thank you. So, when I use as or since, it doesn't care much with tense mismatch. Even if I use present or other tense after past tense or past perfect before as or since.  Am I right?

Comment: The explanation presented in the subordinate clause can express a past fact which is no longer true, a present fact which was also true in the past, or a statement about the future. Any of those statements might be offered as an explanation for something that happened in the past. *Who was that phone call from? --I don't know. The connection dropped right after I said 'hello'. It could have been my sister, since she will be visiting this afternoon.*

Comment: Thank you so much! I have got it. Now just do me a last favor. The sentence you wrote "It could have been my sister, since she will be visiting this afternoon." . Here subordinate clause is "since she will be visiting this afternoon" and principle clause is "It could have been my sister"  Am I right?

Comment: Yes, there is a main clause which can stand on its own independently (*It could have been my sister*) and a subordinate clause which depends on or requires the main clause for it to make full sense (*since she will be visiting this afternoon*).